# Increment number for every 10 lines

Tags: replace, macro

The file consists of 2 columns (code and percentage). We need to add 2 more columns with increasing number for 4th column (Xcols) and increment 3rd column (Ycols) only for every 10 lines with reset of 4th column

SOURCE FILE

```
code,percentage,Ycols,Xcols
52,67.88
233,66.61
119,66.26
37,63.88
21,63.31
85,62.78
22,60.9
109,60.84
96,57.75
51,57.64
210,57.54
205,57.53
113,57.3
97,57.09
66,56.37
10,56.21
49,56.05
248,55.87
68,55.76
87,55.51
29,54.99
93,54.84
11,54.77
186,54.64
27,54.52
220,54.5
89,54.32
151,53.36
47,53.34
212,53.28
```

RESULTANT FILE

```
code,percentage,Ycols,Xcols
52,67.88,1,1
233,66.61,1,2
119,66.26,1,3
37,63.88,1,4
21,63.31,1,5
85,62.78,1,6
22,60.9,1,7
109,60.84,1,8
96,57.75,1,9
51,57.64,1,10
210,57.54,2,1
205,57.53,2,2
113,57.3,2,3
97,57.09,2,4
66,56.37,2,5
10,56.21,2,6
49,56.05,2,7
248,55.87,2,8
68,55.76,2,9
87,55.51,2,10
29,54.99,3,1
93,54.84,3,2
11,54.77,3,3
186,54.64,3,4
27,54.52,3,5
220,54.5,3,6
89,54.32,3,7
151,53.36,3,8
47,53.34,3,9
212,53.28,3,10
```

Comment: This is a great candidate for an awk script. Quick take: `awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; a=1; b=1 } NR == 1 { print; next; } b == 11 { b = 1; a++; } { print $0,a,b++; }' /path/to/file`. Understood if you prefer a Vim solution, though.

Comment: I was struggling with Vim, when awk can do the work so smoothly. Thanks for recalling me to use awk

Comment: Sure. The answers are great but won't win any awards for readability. ;)  Here's a slightly shorter version, fyi: `awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; a=1 } NR==1 { print; next } b==10 { b=0; a++ } { print $0,a,++b }' /path/to/file` . Welcome to Vi&Vim SE.

Comment: You should change your accepted answer from mine to @Jürgen Krämer's, which is essentially the same as mine. Now that he's gone to the trouble of writing a great explanation, I'm unlikely to get around to updating my answer with one. (And as a bonus for me, if you do so, I can delete my answer and snag that elusive [Disciplined](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge!)

Comment: http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/608d040766cd0a0007f52b0d :-D

Comment: Wait. What? This was a Vim Golf question? Or we helped it become a Vim Golf question? Either way, Rich and Jurgen you guys got a long ways to go to get to the current top spot. :D

Comment: This problem was posted by self on both stackoverflow as well as in vimgolf to get solution. This is no intention to get answer for a Vim challenge. Basically this requirement is for creating heatmap visualization in Python using seaborn package. Tried in vim to get the solution and since I could not get the result ans so posted it here and as well as in Vimgolf. I hope you people understand the reality.

Comment: I wasn't leveling any criticism I was just curious about things. I knew you were the author so I didn't think you were trying to "cheat". TBH I've not heard of anyone using Vim Golf as a kind of alternate vim.stackexchange.com. It's none of my business but is that something they're cool with? I figured everyone who posted a challenge had a solution (though not necessarily the lowest scoring one). Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I just gave the clarification. Nothing formal. BTW vimgolf challenge creation needs only input, output and diff files not the solution. Just for curiosity I posted it in vimgolf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file only contains a header line and (starting with line 2) data lines, you can use the `\=` special expression in the replacement text. This allows you to calculate the actual replacement text with an expression consisting of a mix of strings and numeric calculations:

```
:2,$s!$!\=',' . ((line('.') - 2) / 10 + 1) . ',' . ((line('.') - 2) % 10 + 1)!
```

This command changes all data lines. It uses `!` as the separator between search pattern and replacement text, because we need the slash as division operator in the replacement expression. The search pattern is just the end-of-line anchor, thus we will append text at the end of line.

The replacement text consists of two numbers we need to calculate, separated by commas. The first number is (more or less) calculated by dividing the current line number by 10. We subtract 2 from the actual line number, because that's the offset of the first data line into the file, and we add 1, because without that counting of the blocks would start at 0. The second number is the remainder of the same division. Here we also add 1, because otherwise lines in each block would be counted from 0 to 9.

Comment: Excellent answer!